# jsGrid Jquery not loading data

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

This code shows grid definition when run in browser. It also prints to console so I can see array of data is there.  Not showing in grid though, just grid headers.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="jsGrid"></div>
    <script>
        var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var ourData;
        ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/test/data/hello', true);
        ourRequest.onload = function() {
            ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
            console.log(ourData);
        };
        ourRequest.send();

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            width: "50%",
            height: "300",
            pageLoading: true,
            autoload: true,
            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,

            data: ourData,

            fields: [{
                    name: "name",
                    type: "text",
                    width: 150,
                    validate: "required"
                },
                {
                    name: "id",
                    type: "number",
                    width: 50
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by using [`loadData`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#loaddatafilter-promisedataresult) method inside of [`grid-controller`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller).

**SEE DEMO**

```js
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
  width: "100%",
  height: "auto",

  autoload: true,
  paging: true,
  pageSize: 10,
  pageButtonCount: 5,
  pageIndex: 1,

  controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: "//restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all",//you can put your url here.
        dataType: "json"
      });
    }
  },
  fields: [{
      name: 'alpha2Code',
      title: 'Code',
      width: 50
    },{
      name: "name",
      title:'Full Name',
      width: 50
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>


<div id="jsGrid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a snippet of your actual data?

Your `paging` and `pageLoading` are true, so your data has to be of the form:

```
{
  "data": [ { ..first item ...}, { ..second item..}, ...],
  "itemsCount": n 
}
```

`itemsCount` is the total number of records of your data. This is to allow jsGrid to compute the total number of pages.

See http://js-grid.com/docs/#loaddatafilter-promisedataresult